# Given an integer N as input, can you check the following:

Tags: java

Given an integer N as input, can you check the following:

If N  is odd then print "Weird"
If N is even and, in between range 2 and 5(inclusive), print "Not Weird"
If N is even and, in between range 6 and 20(inclusive), print "Weird"
If N is even and , print "Not Weird"

i wrote this code--

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        int ip;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ip = sc.nextInt();        
        if(ip%2==0 ){
           if(ip>=6 || ip<=20){
               System.out.println("Weird");
           }
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
            }
        else{
           System.out.println("Weird"); 
        }
    }
}
```

which fails for 24 -
output-
Weird
Not Weird

expected 
Not Weird.

Could anyone tell my mistake?

Comment: You should really learn how to do debugging in Java programs. That will help you a huge amount, and will help us because there will be less elementary questions to sift through. (you forgot to add an `else` somewhere).

Comment: You're missing an `else` from your `ip>=6 || ip<=20`, as well as using the wrong conditional.

Comment: The statement ``ip>=6 || ip<=20`` is ``true`` for all values of ``ip``.

Answer (score 2):

> print "Not Weird" If N is even and, in between range 6 and
>   20(inclusive)

This states that N should be between 6 and 20 and you wrote

```
if(ip>=6 || ip<=20)
```

This if takes in consideration all `ip` greater or equal to 6 or all `ip` lesser and equal to 20, so all numbers.

You should use the `&&` operator and not the `||` operator

Your code should be:

```
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. 
           Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        int ip;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ip = sc.nextInt();        
        if(ip%2==0 ){
           if(ip>=6 && ip<=20){
               System.out.println("Weird");
           } else {
               System.out.println("Not Weird");
           }
        } else {
           System.out.println("Weird"); 
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `ip >= 6 && ip <= 20` instead of `ip >= 6 || ip <= 20` in if condition

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and easy solution.

It's working for all your conditions.
Hopefully it's clear

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int ip = sc.nextInt(); 
String str=  (ip %2 == 0 &&  ( ip >=2 && ip <= 5 ) || (ip > 20 )) ? "Not Weired" : "Weired"; 
System.out.println(str);
```